# TFS Cloud and Shared Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, shared-libraries, projects-and-solutions, azure-devops

I have just set up an account with TFS Cloud Services and am trying to add my solutions to it.

The problem I'm having is that I have the same shared projects in multiple solutions that I only want to exists once in source control. It seems if I just add the solutions, it will add the shared projects each time under a separate folder for each.

I need only one instance of each shared project so a checkout is reflected across all solutions.

Any ideas how to do this on the TFS Cloud services and VS2010 specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Team Explorer -> Source Control Explorer and use the "add items to folder" to drop in your entire source code directory instead of doing an "add solution to source control" per solution.

[Adding in from the comment below]
Once you have done this you can use the "add solution to source control" for each of your solutions for the bindings to the .sln file. This does the right thing and maintains the folder mapping that you have created via the source explorer and avoids any duplication.

Comment: That has added my files to the repository but the projects aren't linked to it in VS. How do I link them together?

Comment: Once you have done this you can use the "add solution to source control" for each of your solutions for the bindings to the .sln file.  This does the right thing and maintains the folder mapping that you have created via the source explorer and avoids any duplication.